# Attempted to assign to readonly property ECMAScript React Native

Tags: ecmascript-6, react-native

I am trying to assign a value to an array declared in my `Component`. Unfortunately, exception is thrown.

```
TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property
```

Even if I remove `strict` mode, still exception is being raised. Can please someone guide me how can I make a variable both readable and writable? Thanks..!

**Code:**

```
class RootView extends Component {

  cachedData : []; //declared array here


//trying to assign dictionary in some function

someFunction(results) {

    this.cachedData[this.state.searchString.length - 1] = results;
    //exception raised here
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. Add it to a constructor.

```
class RootView extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.cachedData = [];
  }
  someFunction(results) {
    this.cachedData[this.state.searchString.length - 1] = results;
  }
}
```

If your transpiler supports [experimental code](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/experimental/) (stage 0), you can use the following:

```
class RootView extends Component {
  cachedData = [];
  someFunction(results) {
    this.cachedData[this.state.searchString.length - 1] = results;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow `this.cachedData = [];` worked!! But  `cachedData = [];` not working. Thank you so much. Can you tell me how the syntax is wrong?

Comment: You had `cachedData: []`, which is used to assign properties to an object.