# Inserting an item in array every X places and "attempted to assign to readonly property"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of objects coming from the server. I use this to display cards on the screen. I want to insert an "advertisements card" every X cards. I thought I'd done this on the web with the following code, but it seems to not be working with my react-native app.

```
class DeckArea extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){

        let { data, likeJob } = this.props;

        // place an object into the array of jobs data
        data.jobs.forEach((item, i) => {
            let remainder = i%4;        
            if (remainder === 0) {
                console.log(remainder === 0)
                data.jobs.splice(i, 0,{ isAd: true, _id: uuidV4() })
            }
        });


        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Swipe
                  data={data.jobs}
                  renderCard={(job) => {
                    //check if isAd === true, 
                    // if so, show the AdCard not the deck card
                    if (job.isAd) {
                        return <AdCard adsManager={adsManager} />
                    }
                    return <DeckCard job={job} isLikedCard={false} />
                  }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I've done some quick testing and the problem is definitely happening here:

```
           data.jobs.forEach((item, i) => {
                let remainder = i%4;        
                if (remainder === 0) {
                    console.log(remainder === 0)
                    data.jobs.splice(i, 0,{ isAd: true, _id: uuidV4()})
                }
            });
```

resulting in **"attempted to assign to readonly property"**

**Additional resources:**

- [Attempted to assign to readonly property ECMAScript React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343332/attempted-to-assign-to-readonly-property-ecmascript-react-native)
- [Inserting items in an array every nth place in octave / matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196296/inserting-items-in-an-array-every-nth-place-in-octave-matlab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, by inserting in the original jobs array with `data.jobs.splice()`, you are modifying an array passed via props, which is considered to be bad practice.

Instead, you should create a new array, which would include job adds. Example code:

```
// Will show an add after each 4 jobs
const jobsWithAds = data.jobs.reduce((accumulator, job) => {
  const add = { isAd: true, _id: uuidV4() }
  const remainder = accumulator.length % 5; // 5 is needed to include job ad

  // Additional check is required to skip first add
  if (remainder === 0 && accumulator.length > 0) {
    accumulator.concat(add);
  }

  // Add an ad after first 4 jobs, which have no ad
  if (accumulator.length === 4) {
    accumulator.concat(add);
  }

  accumulator.concat(job);
}, [])
```